# pip install doesn't return anything

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I couldn't find any questions that matched my problem. I have had and resolved problems with `pip install` in the past where I received an error message. However, I just reinstalled Python 2.7 and have included the Scripts folder in the PATH (I am using Windows 7; I have verified that pip and easy_install are in the Scripts folder).

Now when I run `pip install`, the command line stalls for a few seconds and then returns an empty command prompt. i.e.:

```
C:\Python27> pip install flask

C:\Python27>
```

I have used pip in the past and know I should either be getting an error message or a list of commands followed by `Cleaning up...`

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you use the latest version of `setuptools` and `pip`?

Comment: @cel how can I tell?

Comment: `pip` doesn't work at all, does it? You can do: `python -c "import pip; print(pip.__version__)"` and similar for setuptools.

Comment: @cel pip version 6.1.1 setuptools version 7.0

Comment: @cel upgraded setuptools to 16.0, but still not getting anything from pip

Comment: That seems fine. Do you get any output from `python -m pip list` or `python -c 'import pip; pip.main(["list"])'`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78239/discussion-between-sam-cd-and-cel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure why that doesn't work but using `python -m pip install` does work

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem, and I solved it by upgrading my pip using the following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```